# without view model file upload is possible or not in database by using asp .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

How I will upload a file in the database **without** using **ViewModel** in asp .net core? Is it possible or not? ***

Advance thanks

Comment: Please provide example code.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  But I already solved it, sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,CategoriesId,Product_Name,Image_path,Add_Date,Price,Quantity,Description")]Product product, IFormFile file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
            }
            else
            {
                string filename = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
                var path = Path.Combine(
                            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "Images", filename);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                byte[] filenamee = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(filename);
                p.Image_path = filenamee;

            }
            _context.Products.Add(p);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["CategoriesId"] = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Id", "Category_Name", product.CategoriesId);
        return View(product);
    }
```